hardhat mempol fifo order is set, but not honored
I am trying to invoke 2 contract methods on one block  in sequence.
I configured my test network:
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.24",
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      gas: "auto",
      blockGasLimit: 123456789000,
      loggingEnabled: true,
      gasPrice: 0,
      initialBaseFeePerGas: 0,
      mining: {
        mempool: {
          order: "fifo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

I disabled auto mining and invoked 2 methods:
            //  disable auto mining
        await hre.network.provider.send("evm_setAutomine", [false]);
        await hre.network.provider.send("evm_setIntervalMining", [0]);

        //  I expect those 2 to be on same block and minbed in this order
        contract.bet(GWEI, 0xFFFFFFFFFF);
        let spinPromise = contract.spin();

       
        //  enable auto moning again
        await hre.network.provider.send("evm_setAutomine", [true]);
        // here I expect spin()  transaction to be rewerted
        await expect(spinPromise).to.be.reverted

Yet those transactions are mined out of order  and on different blocks:
eth_getTransactionReceipt
eth_getTransactionByHash
evm_setAutomine
evm_setIntervalMining
evm_setAutomine
eth_blockNumber (2)
eth_estimateGas (2)
eth_sendTransaction
  Contract call:       Chip#spin
  Transaction:         0xefe0128e556461bd6a67f9aaaf34c5c6b03874ff16e436b917fc791501eb73e5
  From:                0x70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8
  To:                  0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3
  Value:               0 ETH
  Gas used:            27145 of 27145
  Block #3:            0xec7e816cdf5162c480b84ac8e722342dd3b42ac7f63cb5b417fc8b2410df7121

  console.log:
    3 spin 0x70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8

eth_sendTransaction
  Contract call:       Chip#bet
  Transaction:         0xbae056fe3ab516c05797afdce287d2a7750b089ee0291af8b44e87d58f5cdd4f
  From:                0x70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8
  To:                  0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3
  Value:               0 ETH
  Gas used:            201957 of 201957
  Block #4:            0x1f2e93e61c689d8cce7b36addd264d6813735638ea5e76e997bc1d2ea238c833

  console.log:
    4 bet  for 0x70997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c8  1000000000tokens

eth_getTransactionReceipt
eth_getTransactionByHash

it seems that I am missing something simple - but what?
